# How can you access USB from cross-platform Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, usb, usb-drive

I need to copy some files from a PC into a pen drive. I visited JUSB package description, but it is only for windows. So, is there any easy and platform independent way to copy files from computer to USB drive using Java?

Comment: Can you not just mount the USB drive as a filesystem?

Comment: Mount the USB and use the filesystem, probably..?

Comment: USB ports are considered drives. Use that. For example, USB drive in drive X:\, I would write to say X:\test.txt.

Comment: @Gabe: I was way too slow :))

Comment: @Gabe: OK, but how to? I have never worked in this problem domain

Comment: @NiklasR: What did you mean by "Mount" it into the file system?

Comment: see @AdriaanKoster s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the fact that it's a USB drive; when the user inserts the device it is recognized by the OS and shows up as a mounted drive in your filesystem. Then you can just use java.io.File and friends to access it. Additional tip: use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils as a handy toolkit to make many common file-related tasks easier.

If you need to detect the new USB device automatically in Java, that's a bit tricky. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847376/identify-a-new-device-in-java) question.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [libUsb Java Bindings](https://github.com/trygvis/javax-usb-libusb1) a javabinding for [libUsb](http://libusb.org/). Btw. the jUSB API seems to support Linux too (package: `usb.linux`), maybe this article can help you: [Access USB devices from Java applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/)